# Syntax Error: Expected Literal, got 'ORDER'

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sonata

I got this error in symfony 2.8:

```
3/3] Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[Syntax Error] line 0, col 128: Error: Expected Literal, got 'ORDER'").  -
```

line 33 is

```
    {% if admin.datagrid.results|length > 0 %}
```

and

```
 QueryException ::dqlError ('SELECT o FROM Work\SeoControlBundle\Entity\Domain o LEFT JOIN o.strategy s_strategy LEFT JOIN o.renderer s_renderer WHERE ORDER BY o.id ASC')
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php at line 448
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome on SO.

Your `WHERE` condition is empty. Remove it or fill it with needed conditions :)

```
SELECT o FROM Work\SeoControlBundle\Entity\Domain o LEFT JOIN o.strategy s_strategy LEFT JOIN o.renderer s_renderer ORDER BY o.id ASC
```

or

```
SELECT o FROM Work\SeoControlBundle\Entity\Domain o LEFT JOIN o.strategy s_strategy LEFT JOIN o.renderer s_renderer WHERE XXX=YYY ORDER BY o.id ASC
```

Comment: that effectivelly was the error, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change your Repository class files. Remove the where condition because it seems that this is empty.